# How to set editView minimum Width? (Android 2.2)

Tags: android-edittext, android-tablelayout, css

I have a table containing two tableRows each holding four Views: texView, Spinner, editView and texView.

When the content of one of the spinner's childs doesn't fit, it is automatically cut of, which is fine. However I want the editView next to it keep a minimum width of 40dp. Now the width of the textViews are preserved but the editView width is not. How can I achieve that (if not by setting width and/or minwidth as I tried now, see xml file)?

Up until this child's length its fine:
[image: fine]

Now its not so fine:
[image: not fine]

Here's the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Worp "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:tag="SP1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:minWidth="40dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:tag="SP2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:minWidth="40dp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that because of the wrap_content attribute the width of your table column is changing. Try to change the attributes of table row from wrap_content to match_parent or try using weightSum.